# JSON String returned from SOAP web service containing no records for table

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-ksoap2

I have a SOAP web service(.asmx) implemented using the .NET framework that returns me a JSON String in this form:

> {"checkrecord":[{"rollno":"abc2","percentage":40,"attended":12,"missed":34}],"Table1":[]}

Now in my Android app I am using ksoap to call the web service in the following way:

```
    public String getjsondata(String b)
{       

     String be=""; 

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method_NAME);      
        request.addProperty("rollno",b);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
        envelope.dotNet = true; 
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE  android = new HttpTransportSE(url);

        android.debug = true; 

 try 
 {

    //android.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");   
    android.call(soap_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    Log.i("myapp",result.toString());
    System.out.println(" --- response ---- " + result); 
    be=result.toString();

    if (be.startsWith("[")) 
    { // if JSON string is an array
        JSONArr = new JSONArray(be);

        System.out.println("length" + JSONArr.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < JSONArr.length(); i++) 
        {
            JSONObj = (JSONObject) JSONArr.get(i);
            bundleResult.putString(String.valueOf(i), JSONObj.toString());
            System.out.println("bundle result is"+bundleResult);
        } 

     }

   }
    catch (SocketException ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 


    return be;      


 }
```

I am getting a response but the response doesn't contain any records and shows blank values.

Here is response from Logcat:

```
 11-21 20:13:03.283: INFO/myapp(1173): {"checkrecord":[],"Table1":[]}

 11-21 20:13:03.283: INFO/System.out(1173):  --- response ---- {"checkrecord":[],"Table1":[]}
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

My web service code :

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections;
      using System.ComponentModel;
      using System.Data;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Web;
      using System.Web.Services;
      using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
      using System.Xml.Linq;
      using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace returnjson
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]

    public String getdata(String rollno)
    {
        String json;
        try
        {

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123"))
            {

           string select = "select * from checkrecord where rollno=\'" + rollno + "\'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select, myConnection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "checkrecord");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;

        }

        return json;

      }

    }
 }
```

**Edit: I have tested my web service code using a client app on .NET and it is working fine..getting a proper response as per returned JSON String with all records and values.**

Comment: are you sure the answer from the server is that String?

Comment: @njzk2 : yes sure no doubts about that :-)

Comment: Well, if the web service is working for another client, either the request or response logic is incorrect - compare the working and non-working client using TCPMON, and post your results please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's seem this problem  relate to some  specific symbol like : \ lead to soap parse error.

you can use some tool like Ethereal to analyzer the input stream and make sure you have received correctly. if it's right, may be you should encode you json data and then send it.

I just test it on my server(lamp)which return a  JSONObject in body,and android use below code,work normally:

```
public static void testApi() {
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttptt = new AndroidHttpTransport("http://172.16.0.178/1mobile/market/services.php");
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "check_error");
        // request.addProperty("data", "empty");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Element[] header = new Element[1];
        header[0] = new Element().createElement(NAMESPACE, "Credentials");
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.headerOut = header;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(url);
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag(XML_HEAD);
        try {
            androidHttptt.call("http://172.16.0.178/check_error", envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            Log.e("response", "response=" + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

with Etheral,I get the data like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:check_errorResponse xmlns:ns1="http://test.test.com">
<Result xsi:type="xsd:string">{&quot;checkrecord&quot;:[{&quot;rollno&quot;:&quot;abc2&quot;,&quot;percentage&quot;:40,&quot;attended&quot;:12,&quot;missed&quot;:34}],&quot;Table1&quot;:[]}</Result>
</ns1:check_errorResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

You can find the json data have been convered to

```
{&quot;checkrecord&quot;:[{&quot;rollno&quot;:&quot;abc2&quot;,&quot;percentage&quot;:40,&quot;attended&quot;:12,&quot;missed&quot;:34}],&quot;Table1&quot;:[]}
```

Comment: yes,from you description,I thinks it's soap can't parse the json data normally

Comment: ok fine but can u give me an example of a SOAP web service encoding JSON and returning the JSON String ? I have posted my web service code on my post. Can u suggest modifications for it if encoding is to be done?

Comment: @notenking If you really are using Ethereal you may wish to upgrade. We renamed the project to Wireshark way back in 2006. :)

Comment: @notenking: my returned string from the web service is as I have mentioned. I dnt understand why is it showing empty records. You said that it can be a possibility of a / parse error but if that was the case, I wouldn't get any response as such right?

Comment: JObject o=new JObject.parse(json) -> Can this help me convert JSON String into JSONObject that can be returned to my Android app?

Answer (score -1):

SOAP protocol uses XML as means of communication. Your Request will be converted to a XML String and the response from the server will be a XML String which the KSOap parses and gives you an Object. 
So it looks like the response from WebService is fine but there is a problem with KSoap parsing. So as you guys were discussing you can encode the String in the server and return it.
Android already provides support for Base64 encoding/decoding.

In the webservice return the following instead of json.

```
Convert.ToBase64String (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (json));
```

This will return you an encoded string. So the response you will get be an encoded string. So in the android client side.

```
new String(android.util.Base64.decode(responseString.getBytes(),android.util.Base64.DEFAULT))
```

which will give u the decoded string.Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that but still no use same problem? Btw, after decoding in what format will the String be? will it be base64 ?

Comment: Check once again in the WebService whether it is returning properly. After decoding it will be the JSON String. U have encoded the JSon String to Base64 string in the server side and decoding it to get the JSON String

Comment: This is what I get in logcat before and after decoding: http://pastie.org/2937838   ..web service is working fine..it is returning encoded string properly on server side..but server side encoded string and client side response string are not matching because response is containing null records

Comment: come over here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5299/microsoft-net-asp-net-and-asp-net-mvc

Comment: SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

  HttpTransportSE httpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(soapURL);
  httpTransport.call(soapAction, envelope);
  Object resultsRequestSOAP = envelope.getResponse();

Try with this I am using this to call the webservice. I m getting the proper string

Comment: send me a mail on androidparth@gmail.com we will discuss this over chat.

Comment: Please clarify this: what is Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds)  in the line            json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds); in the code ???