# Making of JSON Webservice using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services

I am trying to make JSON webservice in C# .NET. A json string is returning by web method but it contains xml structure like:

```
  <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  {"checkrecord":[{"rollno":"abc2","percentage":40,"attended":12,"missed":34}],"Table1":[]}
  </string>
```

I saw [this](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494) article before it wasn't much helpful for me.

So my problem is, that json string is not returned in its pure format. I do not want that xml version and xmlns string. I plan to consume the web service on Android later.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using a WCF service ?

Comment: I prefer SOAP because I have worked on that for a long time now. If u think WCF is what I need, can u tell me how do I connect to a SQL database, fire a select * query, get the result as dataset, convert dataset to pure json and then return it ?Can u tell me how is it done using WCF because i have no idea of it

Comment: I said that because I have used ksoap to consume many webservices on my client side. I wanted my web service to return a pure json because I am finding it difficult even to return a json String from my webservice. You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213654/json-string-returned-from-soap-web-service-containing-no-records-for-table) to understand my problem better

Comment: to make things clear,I think "Json", because WCF packages are bigger (as seen in feedler),that makes mobile apps. heavier. Beside this using technologies  without proxy generation such as Ksoap wcf's services doesn't make us sense as used commonly with Android. (As a note RestFul services support us proxy generation,also for android+WCF support us OData output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decorate your interface with attributes for request and response format you can get standard WCF to return and interpret proper json.

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "user/{userid}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

The problem is, however, that WCF's innate DataContractJsonSerializer does not always return proper json. Its serialization of dictionaries is problematic at best, since it is serialized as a list of key/value-pairs. To remedy this one has to return `Stream` from the service methods and do the serialization by hand (using Json.NET or ServiceStack to perform the serialization). In such cases it is probably advisable to use WebAPI, but for some cases regular WCF can be used using the mentioned decorations.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to build your service using the REST Api. You can find the information on REST with WCF at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529)

You can download the toolkit for samples on how to build restful wcf services that returns json response.

Answer (score 1):

The [WCF Web API](http://tugberkugurlu.com/archive/introduction-to-wcf-web-api-new-rest-face-ofnet) is worth learning if you plan to create REST services. It's easily installed via Nuget, or from [Codeplex](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP)

Answer (score 1):

This is also not a problem when using ServiceStack, i.e. every result you return get's automatically converted in the Response ContentType you want, i.e. this is the full code of a simple web service that can be called via all HTTP VERBS (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) on all the supported formats (no config required), i.e. JSON, XML, HTML, JSV, CSV, SOAP even by a direct HTML Form **x-www-form-urlencoded** or QueryString request:

```
public class Hello {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse {
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : IService<Hello> {
    public object Execute(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

You can override the response you get with the **Accept:application/json** HTTP Header or simply adding the **?format=json** on the QueryString.

See the [ServiceStack's Hello World Example](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) to see a live example the above web services.

Answer (score 0):

Change return in method for

```
        Context.Response.Write(ans);
        Context.Response.End();
```