# How to change the result from web service into pure JSON variable?

Tags: arrays, json, web-services

I've .NET web service using C#, and I post the result from this web service in JSON Array variable, but there is something strange with my result its not pure JSON variable. How to change it into pure JSON variable?

here is my code:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public ModelReport.Report[] GetReports()
    {
        List<ModelReport.Report> reports = new List<ModelReport.Report>();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnWf"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "select type, sum(OrderQty) as total from tbl_weeklyflash_ID where type <> 'NULL' group by type";
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

            command.CommandText = sql;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ModelReport.Report report = new ModelReport.Report();
                    report.type = reader["type"].ToString();
                    report.total = reader["total"].ToString();
                    reports.Add(report);
                }
            }
        }

        return reports.ToArray();
    }
```

here is my current web service result:

```
-<string>[{"total":"209480","type":"ESL500ML"},{"total":"10177","type":"CHEESE1K"},{"total":"2719928","type":"ESL"},{"total":"145920","type":"WHP"},{"total":"417236.136","type":"UHT"}]</string>
```

and I want to change it into:

```
{"report":[{"total":"209480","type":"ESL500ML"},{"total":"10177","type":"CHEESE1K"},{"total":"2719928","type":"ESL"},{"total":"145920","type":"WHP"},{"total":"417236.136","type":"UHT"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building a `WCF service`. Refer [Making of JSON Webservice using C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308449/making-of-json-webservice-using-c-sharp-net).

You can learn to create WCF services using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2007/10/15/how-to-create-a-hello-world-wcf-service-using-visual-studio.aspx).

Hope it helps.

Comment: so how you did to remove that xml format? you build another web service? you said that you want to use it on android, me too. how you solve this problem?

Comment: yeah I build another webservice using WCF. using ASMX web services you are not able to get pure json, hence I switched over to WCF..that's also similar and easy to consume on Android too..u will find lots of links/codes for the same

Comment: okay, I will try to create another webservice using WCF. thanks :)