# Show DataTable in MVC View

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js, datatable

I would like to bind Employee Details in an HTML table from a DataTable with the help of KnockoutJS. Here is my Model:

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    private string employeeCode;
    private string employeeName;

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Employee Code is Required")]
    public string EmployeeCode
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeCode;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeCode = value;
        }
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name is Required")]
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeName;
        }
        set
        {
            employeeName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller code utilizing the DataTable. I am passing the `List<Employee>` to my View:

```csharp
public JsonResult Get(int customerID)
{
    BAL.Employee dbProvider = new BAL.Employee();

    DataTable dataTable = dbProvider.ShowEmployeeDetails();

    List<Model.Employee> objExerciseList = new List<Model.Employee>();

    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        Model.Employee objExercise = new Model.Employee();

        objExercise.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
        objExercise.EmployeeCode = dataTable.Rows[0]["EmpCode"].ToString();
        objExercise.EmployeeName = dataTable.Rows[0]["EmpName"].ToString();
        objExercise.ContactNumber = dataTable.Rows[0]["ContactNumber"].ToString();
        objExercise.MaritalStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(dataTable.Rows[0]["Is_MaritalStatus"].ToString());
        objExercise.EmailID = dataTable.Rows[0]["EmailID"].ToString();

        objExerciseList.Add(objExercise);
    }

    return Json(objExerciseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And finally here is my View and ViewModel page & code:

```xml
@model IEnumerable<Acidaes.CRMnext.TrainingExercises.Model.Employee>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "exercise7";
  Layout = "../Shared/Master.cshtml";
 }
    <script src="../../Scripts/_references.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div style="width: 990px; background-color: White; height: 710px;">
            <table id="tbllist" align="center" style="border: 5px #fff solid;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">
                        <h2>
                            Employee List</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="padding: 0px;">
                        <div id="title_p">
                            Listing</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th align="left">
                        Employee Code
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                        Employee Name
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                        Contact Number
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                        Marital Status
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                        Email ID
                    </th>
                    <th align="left">
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeCode, new { data_bind = "text: EmpCode" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName, new { data_bind = "text: EmpName" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { data_bind = "text: ContactNumber" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MaritalStatus, new { data_bind = "checked: MaritalStatus" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailID, new { data_bind = "text: EmailID" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         // Initialized the namespace
            var KnockoutDemoNamespace = {};

            // View model declaration
            KnockoutDemoNamespace.initViewModel = function (objExercise) {
                var customerViewModel = {
                    EmpCode: ko.observable(objExercise.EmployeeCode),
                    EmpName: ko.observable(objExercise.EmployeeName),
                    ContactNumber: ko.observable(objExercise.ContactNumber),
                    MaritalStatus: ko.observable(objExercise.MaritalStatus),
                    EmailID: ko.observable(objExercise.EmailID)
                };
                return customerViewModel;
            }

            // Bind the customer
            KnockoutDemoNamespace.bindData = function (objExercise) {
                // Create the view model
                var viewModel = KnockoutDemoNamespace.initViewModel(objExercise);

                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            }

            KnockoutDemoNamespace.getCustomer = function (customerID) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Exercise/Get/",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: "{'customerID':'1' }",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        KnockoutDemoNamespace.bindData(result);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var errorMessage = '';
                        $('#message').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }

            KnockoutDemoNamespace.addCustomer = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Exercise/Add/",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: ko.toJSON(this),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (result) {

                        $('#message').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                KnockoutDemoNamespace.getCustomer(1);

            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I am totally new to KnockoutJS. If my question has any problems, please let me know.

Comment: Try to separate the server and client issues. Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the JSON and a html only view.

Comment: I dont have that much of expertise to create a fiddle..Since it only have HTML in which I can put My .cshtml Code..bt where do i put my Controller.cs & Property defined in Model.cs..If you want me the same to convert in JSON then I dont know..And If i am talking some stupid things..then you can predict my knowledge on Knockout JS..so treat me on that Basis...

Comment: Since you asked... Have a look at [my edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14556740/revisions), these are all things you could do to improve your own questions as well (making it easier and more fun for others to help you). In addition, the more [succinct](http://sscce.org/) you make your questions, the easier (and more likely) it is to help. Finally, be specific about your problem and [tell us what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to solve the problem (currently you're just throwing code out there, it reads like a "Please do this for me" question). Good luck!

Comment: @Jeroen Thank u very much....No body is replying to my question..

Answer (score 2):

KnockoutJS is designed to be used with AJAX and JSON.  Your service should return the data as JSON.

Maybe this will be a good start, [Making of JSON Webservice using C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308449/making-of-json-webservice-using-c-sharp-net)

Comment: But he is returning JSON? "return Json(objExerciseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);"

Comment: how can i return the data as JSON where i am wrong...Since I am totally new..I am not getting it..Can you please explain me..coz I am a milk feeding baby in this field..

Comment: @Richard : Thanks for helping and replying...but that Link too did not help much...And I am not making any kind of WebService...Its just MVC 4 and Knockout Binding..to show a DataTable..

Comment: Knockout is designed for MVC at the client.  Using MVC 4 all the code is on the server.  Either use RAZOR and MVC 4 or use Knockout with a web service that returns JSON.  With KO, the HTML page is static and contains KO markup.  See the tutorial mentions by @delixfe

Comment: I have chosen a project in MVC 4 and Razor...and in that I want knockout binding on one of my .cshtml page to display DataTable....just for learning purpose..

Comment: Then there is no need to use Knockout!

Comment: @Richard : Sir, i am not talking about the need I have to use Knockout Binding...because without knockout i have Successfully made the same page in some other .cshtml page....
How can we achieve the same with help of Knockout JS...
If you can give your precious time..YOU CAN MODIFY MY CODE...
SINCE I HAVE PUT ALL THE THINGS....
the Controller Code,Model and the View Code..
the matter is Showing DATATABLE/DATASET in VIEW through Knockout Binding Syntax

Comment: so that i will have a proper view that what the role will controller play or controller will do nothing...what code should be written in this scenario...and the whole will become an example for me

Comment: I have Updated my VIEWMODEL...Atleast Now Somebody help me out...yaar

Answer (score 1):

You bind your table rows to a list of your employee objects but you have only bound the instances. You can use knockout's foreach binding for that

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: model">
            <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeCode, new { data_bind = "text: EmpCode" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName, new { data_bind = "text: EmpName" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { data_bind = "text: ContactNumber" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MaritalStatus, new { data_bind = "checked: MaritalStatus" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailID, new { data_bind = "text: EmailID" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Do you know knockout's tutorials? They are really great to grasp the concepts: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/